# I’m trying to highlight numbers in table one if they match a number in table two

Tags: excel

I have one table featuring a names, all with 6 separate numbers.

There are 50 names all with 6 numbers associated each.

I’m looking to highlight the numbers within this table, if those numbers appear in table 2.

Can you help.

Comment: Have you considered conditional formatting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’ve tried highlighting the numbers through duplicates in conditional formatting, but it also highlights duplicates held just within table 1. I only want it to highlight table 1 numbers if they match any of the numbers in table 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing your data - how should we help you? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Please use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show us some sample data and the expected outcome.